Integrating $\int_0^\pi 2^x\cos^2(3x)dx$ by parts
I have to compute
$$I=\int_0^\pi 2^x\cos^2(3x)\ dx$$
First, I want to find the primitive. Therefore, let's consider the indefinite integral:
$$J(x)=\int 2^x \cos^2(3x)\ dx$$
and use the integration formula by parts with the following choices:
$$f(x)=\cos^2(3x) \Longrightarrow f'(x)=-6\cos(3x)\sin(3x)=-3\sin(6x)$$
and
$$g'(x)dx=2^x dx\Longrightarrow g(x)=\frac{2^x}{\ln(2)}$$
So, I get
$$J(x)=\frac{2^x\cos^2(3x)}{\ln(2)}+\frac{3}{\ln(2)}\int 2^x\sin(6x)\ dx=(\spadesuit)$$
Now, I repeat the integration by parts choosing:
$$f(x)=\sin(6x) \Longrightarrow f'(x)=6\cos(6x)$$
and
$$g'(x)dx=2^x dx\Longrightarrow g(x)=\frac{2^x}{\ln(2)}$$
So, I get
$$(\spadesuit)=\frac{2^x\cos^2(3x)}{\ln(2)}+\frac{3}{\ln(2)}\left[\frac{2^x\sin(6x)}{\ln(2)}-\frac{6}{\ln(2)}\int 2^x\cos(6x)\ dx\right]=(\clubsuit) $$
Again by parts:
$$f(x)=\cos(6x)\Longrightarrow f'(x)=-6\sin(6x)$$
$$g'(x) dx=2^x \Longrightarrow g(x)=\frac{2^x}{\ln(2)}$$
So, I get
$$(\clubsuit)=\frac{2^x\cos^2(3x)}{\ln(2)}+\frac{3}{\ln(2)}\left[\frac{2^x\sin(6x)}{\ln(2)}-\frac{6}{\ln(2)}\left(\frac{2^x\cos(6x)}{\ln(2)}+\frac{6}{\ln(2)}\int 2^x\sin(6x)\ dx \right)\right]$$
Now, if I set $K(x)=\int 2^x\sin(6x)\ dx$, I obtain that:
$$\frac{3}{\ln(2)}K(x)= \frac{3}{\ln(2)}\left[\frac{2^x\sin(6x)}{\ln(2)}-\frac{6}{\ln(2)}\left(\frac{2^x\cos(6x)}{\ln(2)}+\frac{6}{\ln(2)}K(x)\right)\right]$$
$\iff$
$$\frac{3}{\ln(2)}K(x)=\frac{3\cdot 2^x\sin(6x)}{\ln^2(2)}-\frac{18\cdot 2^x\cos(6x)}{\ln^3(2)}-\frac{108}{\ln^3(2)}K(x)$$
$\iff$
$$\left(\frac{108}{\ln^3(2)}+\frac{3}{\ln(2)}\right)K(x)=\frac{3\cdot 2^x\sin(6x)}{\ln^2(2)}-\frac{18\cdot 2^x\cos(6x)}{\ln^3(2)}$$
$\iff$
$$K(x)=\left(\frac{\ln^3(2)}{108+3\ln^2(2)}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{3\cdot 2^x\sin(6x)}{\ln^2(2)}-\frac{18\cdot 2^x\cos(6x)}{\ln^3(2)}\right)$$
So, finally, I get:
$$J(x)=\frac{2^x\cos^2(3x)}{\ln(2)}+\left(\frac{\ln^3(2)}{108+3\ln^2(2)}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{3\cdot 2^x\sin(6x)}{\ln^2(2)}-\frac{18\cdot 2^x\cos(6x)}{\ln^3(2)}\right)$$
and then:
$$I=J(\pi)-J(0)=\frac{2^\pi}{\ln(2)}-\frac{18\cdot 2^\pi}{108+3\ln^2(2)}-\frac{1}{\ln(2)}+\frac{18}{108+3\ln^2(2)}=$$
$$=\frac{2^\pi-1}{\ln(2)}-\frac{6(2^\pi-1)}{36+\ln^2(2)}=\frac{(2^\pi-1)\left(36+\ln^2(2)-6\ln(2)\right)}{\ln(2)\left(36+\ln^2(2)\right)}$$
I'm pretty sure that there's an error somewhere because the final result doesn't match with the WA result. Moreover, is there a smarter way to do this integral?

I would personally use $\cos (3x) = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos (6x))$ and $\cos(x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$. The integrals become very simple and it's then just some algebra to simplify the resulting complex number.

@whpowell96 Nice approach. I think you meant $\cos^2(3x)$

Ah you're right. That probably wouldn't fly in an undergraduate calculus class but this looks to be more involved than that

@whpowell96 Yeah, I would also use your method if I didn't have to explain this exercise to a high school boy I help who clearly doesn't know complex numbers (unfortunately) nor functions of complex variable. So, I tried my hand at this river of calculations but it's a mess...

Ah I see. If you use the trig identity to get rid of $\cos^2$, I think you will do one fewer integrations by parts. Other than that, I don't think there is a really nice way to do this. This is the method I did when I was in school. Perhaps the tabular method can help to keep track of the bookkeeping?

Why do you work with $\frac{3}{\ln 2} K(x)$ instead of just $K(x)$? I think you forgot some constant factors when substituting $K(x)$ into $J(x)$.

Can you highlight the step in which I forgot some pieces, please?

You used $J(x) = \frac{2^x \cos^2(3x)}{\ln(2)} + K(x)$ instead of $J(x) = \frac{2^x \cos^2(3x)}{\ln(2)} + \frac{3}{\ln(2)} K(x)$.

Oh finally it turns out what doesn't work, thank you very much!

Indeed, by using $\cos^2(3x)=(1+\cos(6x))/2$, you have
$$I=\int_0^\pi 2^{x-1}(1+\cos(6x))dx = \frac{2^\pi -1}{2\ln 2} + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi 2^{x}\cos(6x) dx.$$
We remark
$$ J := \int_0^\pi 2^{x}\cos(6x) \, dx= \frac{-\ln 2}{6}\int_0^\pi 2^{x}\sin(6x) \, dx = \frac{(2^\pi-1)\ln 2}{36} - \frac{(\ln 2)^2}{36}J,$$
which gives
$$J = \frac{(2^\pi-1) \ln 2}{36 + (\ln 2)^2},$$
and finally
$$ I= \frac{(2^\pi-1) \left(18 + (\ln 2)^2\right)}{\left(36 + (\ln 2)^2\right) \ln 2}.$$

This is how I would do it.
$\int_0^\pi 2^x \cos^2 3x \ dx\\
\int_0^\pi e^{x\ln 2}(\frac {e^{3ix} + e^{-3ix}}{2})^2  \ dx\\
\frac 14\int_0^\pi e^{x\ln 2}(e^{6ix} + e^{-6ix} + 2)  \ dx\\
\frac 14\int_0^\pi e^{x(\ln 2+6i)} + 2e^{x\ln 2} + e^{x(\ln 2-6i)}\ dx$
$\frac {e^{x(\ln 2 + 6i)}}{4(\ln 2 + 6i)} + \frac {e^{x\ln 2}}{2\ln 2} + \frac {e^{x(\ln 2 - 6i)}}{4(\ln 2 - 6i)}|_0^\pi$
$\frac {e^{\pi\ln 2}-1}{4(\ln 2 + 6i)} + \frac {e^{\pi\ln 2}-1}{2\ln 2} + \frac {e^{\pi\ln 2}-1}{4(\ln 2 - 6i)}$
$\frac {(\ln 2)(2^\pi-1)}{2(\ln^2 2 +36)} + \frac {2^\pi-1}{2\ln 2}$
$\frac {\ln^2 2 + \ln^2 2 + 36}{2(\ln^2 2 +36)}(2^\pi-1)$
$\frac {\ln^2 2 + 18}{\ln^2 2 +36}(2^\pi-1)$
But you wanted to use integration by parts.
Let $a = \ln 2$
$I=\int e^{ax} \cos^2 3x$
$u=\cos^2 3x, dv = e^{ax} \ dx\\
du = 3\sin 6x\ dx, v = \frac {e^{ax}}{a}$
$\frac {e^{ax} \cos^2 3x}{a}_0^\pi - \frac {3}{a} \int_0^\pi e^{ax} \sin 6x\ dx$
$\frac {e^{a\pi}-1}{a} - \frac {3}{a} \int_0^\pi e^{ax} \sin 6x\ dx$
$u=\sin 6x, dv = e^{ax} \ dx\\
du = 6\cos 6x\ dx, v = \frac {e^{ax}}{a}$
$\frac {e^{a\pi}-1}{a} - \frac {3e^{ax}\sin 6x}{a^2}_0^\pi + \frac {36}{a^2}\int e^{ax}\cos 6x\ dx$
$\frac {e^{a\pi}-1}{a} + \frac {18}{a^2}\int e^{ax}(2\cos^2 3x - 1) dx$
$I = \frac {e^{a\pi}-1}{a} + \frac {36}{a^2}I + \frac {18(e^a\pi - 1)}{a^3}$
$(a^2 - 36)I = a(e^{a\pi}-1) + \frac {18(e^a\pi - 1)}{a}$
$I = \frac {a^2 + 18}{a(a^2-36)}(e^{a\pi} - 1)\\
\frac {\ln^2 2 + 18}{\ln 2(\ln^2 2 + 36)}(2^\pi - 1)$
